# How can I log into several Outlook accounts online at the same time?

Tags: outlook.com

I have two accounts, one `@live.co.uk` and another `@hotmail.co.uk`. I used to be able to log into one and then switch between the accounts without signing out/in again by using the menu in the top right.

A while ago my email accounts disappeared from that menu; how can I get this feature back?

Comment: Are you open to linking the two accounts but using one as an alias for the other? Or do you want be able to log in to two separate accounts?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Microsoft have [discontinued this feature](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/06/17/microsoft-to-switch-linked-accounts-off-on-outlook-com/).